# Can someone identify this unmarked, brown, disc-shaped component?

Tags: identification, components

I got a bag of these in a box lot of "amplifier parts" on eBay.  What are they?
The only measurement I can get with my meter is 10M ohms...

[image: mystery component]

Comment: No markings or writing on the component?

Comment: None just the orange dot on each.

Answer (score 4):

It appears to be a fried Metal Oxide Varistor or Thermistor.

Comment: MOV sounds right.  Never installed, so not fried.  But I believe they have a shelf life.

Comment: It appears so! The original colour may have been orange. Shelf life is not an issue. Degradation occurs only due to voltage spikes encountered in operation.

Answer (score 1):

As vu2nan says it is most likely a MOV (metal oxide varistor) which will have a high resistance until a large voltage is applied across it.

The exact voltage is hard to tell without a power supply that can generate a sufficient voltage; possibly above 200-300 volts, as it is often used to protect the input of AC line circuits.

Read more here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varistor